# Code Complexity in cobertura tool

Tags: java, eclipse, cobertura, code-complexity

I am using cobertura tool in my EclipseSDK 3.8.1 . I am able to run the coverage, but is there any option to check the complexity of the code through this tool?. All I can view is the code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to find the complexity, just update your eclipse by, Help | Software Updates | Find and Install| http://metrics.sourceforge.net/update | OK | Right-click your project and select the Properties menu. In the resulting window, select the Enable Metrics plugin check box and click OK. 
Select the Window menu from Eclipse to open the Metrics view and then select Show View | Other....
Select the Metrics | Metrics View to open the window
Under McCabe Cyclomatic complexity you can view the complexity of your code now.